# Which parameters to use with FFMPEG to rectify Mars Ingenuity helicopter images?

Tags: mars, ingenuity, image-processing

I know how to convert a fisheye image to equirectangular, to view it inside a 3D VR viewer as a "panorama":

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -vf v360:fisheye:equirectangular:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:pitch=0 -y output.jpg
```

- -i input file
- -vf video filter

  - v360: VR360 panorama conversion

    - fisheye: source format
    - equirectangular: destination format
    - ih_fov: input horizontal FOV
    - iv_fov: input verticalFOV
    - pitch: camera up/down orientation
  - -y Overwrite
  - Output file

Instead I would like to "rectify" the Ingenuity fisheye image, as if it was shot with a standard camera; I know about **[lensfun](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#lensfun)** and **[lenscorrection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#lenscorrection)** parameters , but I don't undrestand which parameters I should use.

Cameras official data:

> **Navigation (NAV) Camera** has a ﬁeld-of-view (FOV) of 133 deg
> (horizontal) by 100 deg (vertical) with an average Instantaneous
> Field-of-view (IFOV) of 3.6 mRad/pixel

> **Return-to-Earth (RTE) Camera**  has a FOV of 47 deg (horizontal) by 47 deg (vertical) with
> an average IFOV of 0.26 mRad/pixel.

> The NAV camera is pointed directly towards nadir, and the RTE camera
> is pointed approximately 22 deg below the horizon, resulting in an
> overlap region between the two camera image footprints of
> approximately 30 deg × 47 deg.

Source: https://rotorcraft.arc.nasa.gov/Publications/files/Balaram_AIAA2018_0023.pdf

Full FFMPEG documentation: [link](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html)

Ingenuity raw images: https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/multimedia/raw-images/index.cfm?af=REAR_HAZCAM_RIGHT

Comment: Consider asking at a software oriented SE like [SO] or [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [Linux&Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this looks like a software or photography or physics related question than space related. It may get a quicker answer at another site.

Comment: I think your ['partial answer, too big for a comment'](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/58372/12102) is particularly helpful and doesn't need to be deleted. It's a big morbid to talk about, but if the parachutes are for example heat damaged and fail somehow then they might need to look for a [debris field like was seen during searches for MH-370](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370#Marine_debris). Even if and probably *especially if* the astronauts don't survive it will be essential to recover the breached or fragmented spacecraft to try to understand what went wrong.

Comment: Also, I noticed that most of the close voters here are not particularly active members of the community, and we have plenty of questions about using software and analyzing data from spacecraft. "[I’m voting to close this question because this looks like a software or photography or physics related question than space related](https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/176949)" offers a false choice - in this case it's about both. I think it's clear now that the community agrees we shouldn't close questions because we think it's "better asked" elsewhere.

Comment: The bar is simply if it is demonstrably off-topic here or not, and your question is not off-topic! ["I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Physics SE" is bad and here's why](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2866/12102) Future readers in Space SE will benefit from finding an answer here. Normally I'd just vote to reopen and add a bounty (I like adding bounties to things!), but you might have some specific reason why you'd like to leave it closed so I'll wait to see if you object.